# Loading crystal report failed - Invalid field name containing curly brackets

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have about 700 crystal XI reports with some of them containing closing curly brackets in the formula-field **names** like "**Test }**". Even though Crystal Reports XI can open all of them, C# crashes at the attempt of loading such reports.

This is the code I use to load the reports (which for other reports works fine)

```cs
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument reportDocument; 
reportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

reportDocument.Load(path); //Application crashes here
```

**Following exception is thrown:**

```cs
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Load report failed 
Invalid field name
```

**So my question is** if there is any possibility of regardlessly loading these reports? If not, is a newer version of the crystal reports DLLs capable of loading older reports?

**Some further information about the problem:**
I am using Visual Studio 2012 C# .NET 4.5 with the platform target set to x86
As for the Crystal DLLs I use the version 11.0.3300

Surprisingly C# hasn't any problems loading reports with field names containing opening curly brackets or many other special characters:

"**Test }**" or "**{Test }**" - Error
"**{ Test**" or "**Test {**" - Loading without problems - so opening curly brackets work just fine
"**" Test < >= % & |"**" - Loading aswell without any problems (Yes the name contains double quotes)

#### Edit: Because of unavoidable confusion:

Please keep in mind that the problem is about the formula field **names** and **not** the formula itself. Example Image:

[image: Example Image]

-> At the moment I see only one solution, as the problem seems to be a combination of the API and C#: Rename all formula field names and remove the brackets

Original Exception Message:

```cs
{"Der Bericht konnte nicht geladen werden."} //Load report failed
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HelpLink: null
HResult: -2146233088
InnerException: {"\rUngültiger Feldname.\nC:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\  
  {566E74ED-58BF-40CD-82B2-9AE0E6BC4013}.rpt"} //Invalid field name
Message: "Der Bericht konnte nicht geladen werden."
Source: "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine"
StackTrace: " at 
  CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() \r\n at 
  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, 
  OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)\r\n at 
  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) \r\n at 
  CRTableLister.ReportAnalyzer.analyzeReport(String path)"
TargetSite: {Void EnsureDocumentIsOpened()}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know crystal report {} are used when you drag drop a field from dataset to report formula. And after dragging it becomes like `{TableName.ColumnName}` in your formulas and formulas are represented as `@formulaName` without any white spaces. In general we dont prefer any spaces between the column names.

Here is a sample basic formula

```
Global BalQty As Number           - declares the global variable Balqty as an Integer
if {Table.Flag} = 1 Then                        - if the record is Receipt of Stock
BalQty = {Table.qtyRec} + Balqty       - Add to the cumulative value of Balqty
else                                          - otherwise
BalQty = BalQty – {Table.qtyDispa}
endif
Formula  = Balqty             - Return Balqty
```

Let it is saved as MyFormula. So when I drag drop it on the report it will get displayed as @MyFormula. And I think it will work on any version of Crystal Report.

### Finally I can say, you need to check your formulas.

All these examples are from Crystal Report Basic for VS2008.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Amit. But I'm really sorry as I didn't manage to fully explain the problem. I now added an image to the problem for better understanding. The problem is that the formula field **name** contains brackets and **Not** the formula itself, which is indeed odd. The formula field names have manually been changed. Please also have a look at the comments on campagnolo's solution. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your Crystal Reports for VS is out of date. They are up to 13.x now, so I'd suggest to get the latest version. You can download it [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074). Make sure to download the exe, not the msi. I believe the exe is the first on the list, check the hyperlink when hovering over them. You might also want to uninstall your current version before installing the new one.

EDIT:

After seeing the screenshot, there shouldn't be any brackets around the formula name. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have actually just done that and the exception still occurs - so it's probably supposed not to be allowed to use } in field names. But Crystal Reports XI allows it and it works.

Comment: Luke, I'm not yet convinced that the "{}" are your problem. Have you checked permissions on the files/folders where the reports are stored and on your C:\Temp folder? Also, are you using IIS? If so, give it a restart.

Comment: I'm using a Windows Forms application and load the reports from a selected folder in a FolderBrowserDialog. When I open the report using Crystal Reports XI and remove the curly bracket, the exactly same report will load without problems. Therefore I think it might not be a permission problem.

Comment: Could you post the code for one of those formulas? Also, have you checked that the field names are identical in your dataset and your query (since it's a windows form I'm assuming you are using dataset(s)?

Comment: As for datasource I'm using ODBC. So the code for one of this formula is for example: {HRMDAT.MPNAME} This would work fine, if the field name itself wasn't {Department} - If I remove the brackets of the field name it works. For further illustration have a look at this image: [Image of Field](http://s17.postimg.org/szt6av8aj/fieldname.png). Thank you very much

Comment: Luke, I looked at your screenshot and there shouldn't be curly brackets around the formula name. I looked at 3 different versions of Crystal, and none puts the brackets around the formula names. Please see the screenshot I added to my answer. So did you add those brackets or where did they come from?

Comment: I totally agree with you that there **shouldn't** be any brackets around the Formula name. But certain people have manually entered those brackets and since Crystal XI accepts those brackets and even processes the report without problems, nobody has removed them. The problem in my opinion is, that Crystal XI accepts them and the DLL API doesn't. - I'm just glad the API loads reports with field names like "Testfield <= BP" - **Not** the code, but the **Name** and yes, with the quotes **in** the name...

Comment: Well, my guess is that C# thinks the curlies are some sort of method or instruction whereas Crystal doesn't care since it thinks it's just a name. The reason the field names with quotes work is probably because C# thinks it's a string and that doesn't matter much. I don't think there is a solution here other than either removing the curlies or putting quotes around the name, either of which means you have some manual labor to do.